# Boxplot for paired observations

Tags: matlab, statistics, data-visualization, visualization, boxplot

I am looking to plot boxplots for paired observations (with individual data points) in MATLAB, similar to the output of R's [`ggpaired`](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/132-plot-grouped-data-box-plot-bar-plot-and-more/#add-p-values-and-significance-levels):

[image]

I could do the boxplots with the `boxplot` function, but I don't know how to plot the individual data points and the lines connecting the pairs of observations.

My code so far:

```
load('MMN_Adult_Amp.mat');
load('Condition.mat');
figure;
boxplot(MMN_Adult_Amp, Condition)
xlabel('Condition','FontSize', 10)
ylabel('Amplitude (\muV)','FontSize', 10)
box off
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: I think there were plans to add something like this in a future MATLAB release. Please show us your present code. The effect you're missing can be achieved using `hold on` then some more plots (`plot`, `scatter` and/or `line`).

Comment: Thank you ! I have added my current code

Comment: @VPeter have you tried what Dev-iL suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`parallelcoords`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/parallelcoords.html) might come in handy here:

```matlab
function q54528239
%% Load some sample data:
measures = struct2array(load('fisheriris','meas'));
%% Plot
figure();
coordLineStyle = 'k.';
boxplot(measures(1:20,1:2), 'Symbol', coordLineStyle); hold on;
parallelcoords(measures(1:20,1:2), 'Color', 0.7*[1 1 1], 'LineStyle', '-',...
  'Marker', '.', 'MarkerSize', 10);
end
```

[image]

However, it requires the *Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox*. If you don't have this toolbox, the same can be achieved using line plots:

```matlab
function q54528239
%% Load some sample data:
measures = struct2array(load('fisheriris','meas'));
nCats = 2;
nDatas = 20;
%% Plot
figure();
boxplot(measures(1:nDatas, 1:nCats), 'Symbol', 'k.'); hold on;
line(repmat([(1:nCats).';NaN], [nDatas,1]), ...
  reshape(measures(1:nDatas,[1:nCats, 1]).', [], 1), ...
  'Color', 0.7*[1 1 1], 'Marker', '.', 'MarkerSize', 10);
end
```

The result of the above is visually identical, but there's some difference in terms of the tooltips of the points (which are slightly more informative in the first case).

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first option (using statistics and machine learning toolbox) and it worked!